# PlayFramework : Display data from 2-table join, having 2 different bean

Tags: jpa, join, playframework, javabeans

I have 2 tables and 2 beans, these beans mapped with tables.

Table - Bean : 
m_student - MStudentBean.java 
m_book - MBook.java

Now, I have to display data like 
student_id , student_name , student_contact + book_nums , book_names.

For this I have to join both tables and then display the data.
I want to know that how to return data in views - 
I can make new bean and then populate data in bean using join query & return this bean for display. Is it good idea to make new bean here ?
OR
I can make list where based on student_id populate both tables data in respective bean and then add both bean in list and then return this list for display.

How to do this in playframework.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful link for above issue -

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JPA/OneToManyMappedBy.htm

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-one-to-many-annotation-tutorial/

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.